# SQL Server-How to avoid repetition of a column in the output

Tags: sql, sql-server

Output of my SQL Server Query is as below:

[image]

Following is my query:

```
SELECT 
   si.SupplyInvoiceID,
   si.CompanyID,
    si.TotalBill,
   siph.BillPaidAmount,
   si.TotalBill - SUM(siph.BillPaidAmount) 
   over( partition by si.SupplyInvoiceID order by siph.SupplyPaymentID  asc) as RemainingBillAmount

from
   SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph 
   left join
      SupplyInvoice si 
      on siph.SupplyInvoiceID = si.SupplyInvoiceID
```

I want that in output column `TotaBill`, bill amount should be shown only one for each `SupplyInvoiceID` i.e

**Required Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem requires an ordering for the table.  It appears to be by `SupplyPaymentId` (although any column can be used).  To do what you want, you can use `row_number()` and an explicit `order by` in the query:

```
select si.SupplyInvoiceID, si.CompanyID,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY si.SupplyInvoiceID order by siph.SupplyPaymentID) = 1
             THEN si.TotalBill
        END) as TotalBill
       siph.BillPaidAmount,
       (si.TotalBill -
        SUM(siph.BillPaidAmount) over (partition by si.SupplyInvoiceID order by siph.SupplyPaymentID asc)
       ) as RemainingBillAmount
from SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory siph left join
     SupplyInvoice si 
     on siph.SupplyInvoiceID = si.SupplyInvoiceID 
order by si.SupplyInvoiceID, siph.SupplyPaymentID
```